# Returning a list of sites with web scraping available

Tags: python, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, data-analysis

I am completely new to Python and am starting a web scraping project. I have a dataframe that looks like the following

| ID | Website |
| --- | --- |
| 0001 | [www.website1.com](http://www.website1.com) |
| 0002 | [www.website2.com](http://www.website2.com) |
| ..... | ..... |
| 9999 | [www.website9999.com](http://www.website9999.com) |

Some of these sites will not allow web scraping using `BeautifulSoup` so my first step will be to filter out a list of websites that allow web scraping. I tried this using the following:

```
x = requests.get(df["Website"])
x.status_code
```

If the lines above aren't clear, my goal is to return a list composed of either [200] or [404] to show which sites work and which ones do not. Once the list is returned, I will filter out the [404] error codes and focus on extracting the [200] websites.

Either way, my syntax is probably off or I am approaching this an incorrect way. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: After trying this through a for loop, I get the following error:

```
for x in df['Website']:
  requests.get(x)
```

```
MissingSchema                             Traceback (most recent call last)
C:my_path.py in <module>
      1 for x in df['Website']:
----> 2   requests.get(x)
```

Comment: Are you getting errors? Is something not working as expected?

Comment: Yes, I am getting the error 

"InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for (list of websites)Name: Website, Length: 8696, dtype: object'

Comment: The argument to `requests.get` should be a string. What is the value of `df["Website"]`? My guess is that it's a list (or list-like), and you will need to iterate over it, calling `request.get` once for each item.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues here.

First, you haven't provided us with information about the data you're passing to your code. I'm going to assume it's a pandas `DataFrame` that looks something like:

```
>>> df
   id         website
0   1  www.google.com
1   2   www.kodak.com
2   3  www.mentos.com
>>> list(df['website'])
['www.google.com', 'www.kodak.com', 'www.mentos.com']
```

Initially, you were passing a list of websites to `requests.get`:

```
x = requests.get(df["Website"])
```

This won't work, because `requests.get` expects a single string as the first argument, not a list or list-like object. You need to iterate over the column values, something like:

```
>>> for website in df['website']:
...     res = requests.get(website)
...     print(res)
```

But this will fail with:

```
requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL 'www.google.com': No scheme supplied. Perhaps you meant http://www.google.com?
```

As the error message suggests, the problem here is that you're passing in hostnames rather than URLs. You need to add a schema, either `http://` or `https://`. For example:

```
>>> for website in df['website']:
...     res = requests.get(f'http://{website}')
...     print(res)
```

Which results in:

```
<Response [200]>
<Response [200]>
<Response [200]>
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help. When I ran the above for loop, I got the error message:

```
SSLCertVerificationError                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    698             # Make the request on the httplib connection object.
--> 699             httplib_response = self._make_request(
    700                 conn,
```

Comment: You're getting a certificate verification error, which you only get when using `https` connections if your client (`requests`) doesn't recognize the authority that signed the certificate presented by the remote site. While generally inadvisable, for what you're doing you can try configuring `requests` to ignore certificate verification failures: `requests.get(f'http://{website}', verify=False)`. You'll still get warnings, but the requests will complete.

Comment: Thanks. This worked for the first few websites but about 5 lines in I got the error

`ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='www.(website).com', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000001AFFBB66CA0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed')`.

I checked, and this website is no longer running. How can we enable the for loop to skip if the domain no longer exists? Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: I think we've solved the issues in your original question. If you think this has been helpful, please feel free to check the checkmark to the left of this question. If you're having additional problems with your code, I would suggest opening a new question, and including sufficient details for other folks to help out. With respect to dealing with the connection errors, you'll probably want to learn about exceptions and `try`/`except` blocks.